# Python custom method set to new variable changes old variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have created a class with two methods, `NRG_load` and `NRG_flat`. The first loads a CSV, converts it into a DataFrame and applies some filtering; the second takes this DataFrame and, after creating two columns, it `melt`s the DataFrame to pivot it.

I am trying out these methods with the following code:

```
nrg105 = eNRG.NRG_load('nrg_105a.tsv')
nrg105_flat = eNRG.NRG_flat(nrg105, '105')
```

where `eNRG` is the class, and '105' as second argument is needed to run an if-loop within the method to create the aforementioned columns.

The behaviour I cannot explain is that the second line - the one with the `NRG_flat` method - changes the `nrg105` values.

Note that if I only run the `NRG_load` method, I get the expected DataFrame.

**What is the behaviour I am missing?** Because it's not the first time I apply a syntax like that, but I never had problems, so I don't know where I should look at.

Thank you in advance for all of your suggestions.

EDIT: as requested, here is the class' code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Apr 16 15:22:21 2019

@author: CAPIZZI Filippo Antonio
"""

import pandas as pd
from FixFilename import FixFilename as ff
from SplitColumn import SplitColumn as sc
from datetime import datetime as ddt


class EurostatNRG:
    # This class includes the modules needed to load and filter
    # the Eurostat NRG files

    # Default countries' lists to be used by the functions
    COUNTRIES = [
        'EU28', 'AL', 'AT', 'BE', 'BG', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DK', 'EE', 'EL',
        'ES', 'FI', 'FR', 'GE', 'HR', 'HU', 'IE', 'IS', 'IT', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV',
        'MD', 'ME', 'MK', 'MT', 'NL', 'NO', 'PL', 'PT', 'RO', 'SE', 'SI', 'SK',
        'TR', 'UA', 'UK', 'XK'
    ]

    # Default years of analysis
    YEARS = list(range(2005, int(ddt.now().year) - 1))

    # NOTE: the 'datetime' library will call the current year, but since
    # the code is using the 'range' function, the end years will be always
    # current-1 (e.g. if we are in 2019, 'current year' will be 2018).
    # Thus, I have added "-1" because the end year is t-2.

    INDIC_PROD = pd.read_excel(
        './Datasets/VITO/map_nrg.xlsx',
        sheet_name=[
            'nrg105a_indic', 'nrg105a_prod', 'nrg110a_indic', 'nrg110a_prod',
            'nrg110'
        ],
        convert_float=True)

    def NRG_load(dataset, countries=COUNTRIES, years=YEARS, unit='ktoe'):
        # This module will load and refine the NRG dataset,
        # preparing it to be filtered

        # Fix eventual flags
        dataset = ff.fix_flags(dataset)

        # Load the dataset into a DataFrame
        df = pd.read_csv(
            dataset,
            delimiter='\t',
            encoding='utf-8',
            na_values=[':', ': ', ' :'],
            decimal='.')

        # Clean up spaces from the column names
        df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()

        # Removes the mentioned column because it's not needed
        if 'Flag and Footnotes' in df.columns:
            df.drop(columns=['Flag and Footnotes'], inplace=True)

        # Split the first column into separate columns
        df = sc.nrg_split_column(df)

        # Rename the columns
        df.rename(
            columns={
                'country': 'COUNTRY',
                'fuel_code': 'KEY_PRODUCT',
                'nrg_code': 'KEY_INDICATOR',
                'unit': 'UNIT'
            },
            inplace=True)

        # Filter the dataset
        df = EurostatNRG.NRG_filter(
            df, countries=countries, years=years, unit=unit)

        return df

    def NRG_filter(df, countries, years, unit):
        # This module will filter the input DataFrame 'df'
        # showing only the 'countries', 'years' and 'unit' selected

        # First, all of the units not of interest are removed
        df.drop(df[df.UNIT != unit.upper()].index, inplace=True)

        # Then, all of the countries not of interest are filtered out
        df.drop(df[~df['COUNTRY'].isin(countries)].index, inplace=True)

        # Finally, all of the years not of interest are removed,
        # and the columns are rearranged according to the desired output
        main_cols = ['KEY_INDICATOR', 'KEY_PRODUCT', 'UNIT', 'COUNTRY']
        cols = main_cols + [str(y) for y in years if y not in main_cols]
        df = df.reindex(columns=cols)

        return df

    def NRG_flat(df, name):
        # This module prepares the DataFrame to be flattened,
        # then it gives it as output

        # Assign the indicators and products' names
        if '105' in name:  # 'name' is the name of the dataset
            # Creating the 'INDICATOR' column
            indic_dic = dict(
                zip(EurostatNRG.INDIC_PROD['nrg105a_indic'].KEY_INDICATOR,
                    EurostatNRG.INDIC_PROD['nrg105a_indic'].INDICATOR))
            df['INDICATOR'] = df['KEY_INDICATOR'].map(indic_dic)
            # Creating the 'PRODUCT' column
            prod_dic = dict(
                zip(
                    EurostatNRG.INDIC_PROD['nrg105a_prod'].KEY_PRODUCT.astype(
                        str), EurostatNRG.INDIC_PROD['nrg105a_prod'].PRODUCT))
            df['PRODUCT'] = df['KEY_PRODUCT'].map(prod_dic)
        elif '110' in name:
            # Creating the 'INDICATOR' column
            indic_dic = dict(
                zip(EurostatNRG.INDIC_PROD['nrg110a_indic'].KEY_INDICATOR,
                    EurostatNRG.INDIC_PROD['nrg110a_indic'].INDICATOR))
            df['INDICATOR'] = df['KEY_INDICATOR'].map(indic_dic)
            # Creating the 'PRODUCT' column
            prod_dic = dict(
                zip(
                    EurostatNRG.INDIC_PROD['nrg110a_prod'].KEY_PRODUCT.astype(
                        str), EurostatNRG.INDIC_PROD['nrg110a_prod'].PRODUCT))
            df['PRODUCT'] = df['KEY_PRODUCT'].map(prod_dic)

        # Delete che columns 'KEY_INDICATOR' and 'KEY_PRODUCT', and
        # rearrange the columns in the desired order
        df.drop(columns=['KEY_INDICATOR', 'KEY_PRODUCT'], inplace=True)
        main_cols = ['INDICATOR', 'PRODUCT', 'UNIT', 'COUNTRY']
        year_cols = [y for y in df.columns if y not in main_cols]
        cols = main_cols + year_cols
        df = df.reindex(columns=cols)

        # Pivot the DataFrame to have it in flat format
        df = df.melt(
            id_vars=df.columns[:4], var_name='YEAR', value_name='VALUE')

        # Convert the 'VALUE' column into float numbers
        df['VALUE'] = pd.to_numeric(df['VALUE'], downcast='float')

        # Drop rows that have no indicators (it means they are not in
        # the Excel file with the products of interest)
        df.dropna(subset=['INDICATOR', 'PRODUCT'], inplace=True)

        return df
```

EDIT 2: if this could help, this is the error I receive when using the `EurostatNRG` class in IPython:

> [autoreload of EurostatNRG failed: Traceback (most recent call last): 
>   File
>   "C:\Users\CAPIZZIF\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py",
>   line 244, in check
>       superreload(m, reload, self.old_objects)   File "C:\Users\CAPIZZIF\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py",
>   line 394, in superreload
>       update_generic(old_obj, new_obj)   File "C:\Users\CAPIZZIF\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py",
>   line 331, in update_generic
>       update(a, b)   File "C:\Users\CAPIZZIF\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py",
>   line 279, in update_class
>       if (old_obj == new_obj) is True:   File "C:\Users\CAPIZZIF\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py",
>   line 1478, in **nonzero**
>       .format(self.**class**.**name**)) ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or
>   a.all(). ]

Comment: We will need to see the class's code.

Comment: As @brunns mentioned, we need to check those methods. Probably the `NRG_flat` method is changing the first parameter in-place

Comment: try just doing `nrg105_flat = eNRG.NRG_flat(nrg105.copy(), '105')`. As others have said, you are probably changing the parameter inplace

Comment: Thank you all for your replies, I have added the class code in the original post.

Comment: Your class definition uses all *class level variables*. You even call the methods explicitely through the class. You need to use instance variables, and properly define your methods to accept `self` as the first parameter. Frankly, this is all wrong. you should read the documentation on classes: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: Hello @juanpa.arrivillaga, thank you for pointing that out.
I have used _class level variables_ because - in this and other classes - they are used by diverse methods, so they are common to more than one method.

Comment: @FilippoAntonioCapizzi **that's what instance variables are for**. Again, your class definitions demonstrates a fundamental misunderstanding of Python's class model. You aren't using **any internal state**. You might as well just write a bunch of module-level functions with some global variables. Please understand, I am merely trying to give you constructive criticism. Please read: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html Python's class model is simple, but may be subtly different if coming from a different language

Comment: Your comment makes me understand I understood wrong how a class in Python is structured, so: **thank you!** I really took your comment as constructive, because I really thought I understood how to write classes and methods, but finally I get a feedback on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the culprit.

In the `NRG_flat` method, the lines:

```
df['INDICATOR'] = df['KEY_INDICATOR'].map(indic_dic)
...
df['PRODUCT'] = df['KEY_PRODUCT'].map(indic_dic)
```

mess up the copies of the `df` DataFrame, thus I had to change them with the [Pandas `assign` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df = df.assign(INDICATOR=df.KEY_INDICATOR.map(prod_dic))
...
df = df.assign(PRODUCT=df.KEY_PRODUCT.map(prod_dic))
```

I do not get any more error.

Thank you for replying!